# Make my mac use updated 10.9 SDK

Tags: xcode, macos, sdk, operating-system, osx-mavericks

It appears that my mac is using the 10.8 SDK even though I'm on OSX 10.9. I suspect that this is the case because my mac does not recognize the function `SecTrustSetNetworkFetchAllowed` in `SecTrust.h`. The function was only included in `SecTrust.h` supplied in the 10.9 SDK.

Is there a way I can force my mac to use the 10.9 SDK? Thanks!

Comment: which version of Xcode you are using?

Comment: @DevaraGudda Version 6.0